# ClickLock: Enable Drag after Long Click

Tags: macos, trackpad, accessibility

I am new user of Macbook and I love it, but  I need ClickLock feature (Like on Windows Mouse Settings) because I have cerebral palsy and I can't drag normally.

**The idea of ClickLock feature:** Long click (~30ms) to enable dragging and click to turn of.

Any ideas how to do it?

The best,
Lukasz

Answer (score 2):

I trust that the *Drag Lock* feature should deliver what you need. You can activate it in the [system preferences](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18396?locale=en_GB). I would also suggest that you have a look at [this discussion](http://apple.stackexchange./questions/7109/whats-the-difference-between-one-finger-dragging-and-drag-lock) that explains how the drag and lock an similar options work.

Comment: Thank  you for answer, however it isn`t exactly what I need because the DragLock works only for touch, but not click.